# Comparar o que está escrito em um button com o campo em php

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estou realizando um site de perguntas e respostas, alternativas embaralhadas e etc.

Estou com problema em saber em que a alternativa o usuário clicou e se corresponde ou não com o que está escrito no campo "altercerta" do banco (MariaDB).
Porem não tenho ideia de como fazer isso, a seguir está os codigos com que estou tentando fazer funcionar (obviamente não estão funcionando)

```
<button type="button" ng-class="p1a1" style="float: center;width: 80%" ng-click="p1click(1)"><?php echo $alternativas1[0] ?></button>         <br><br>
<button type="button" ng-class="p1a2" style="float: center;width: 80%" ng-click="p1click(2)"><?php echo $alternativas1[1] ?></button>         <br><br>
<button type="button" ng-class="p1a3" style="float: center;width: 80%" ng-click="p1click(3)"><?php echo $alternativas1[2] ?> </button>        <br><br>
<button type="button" ng-class="p1a4" style="float: center;width: 80%" ng-click="p1click(4)"><?php echo $alternativas1[3] ?></button>         <br><br>
<button type="button" ng-class="p1a5" style="float: center;width: 80%" ng-click="p1click(5)"><?php echo $alternativas1[4] ?></button>         <br><br>
```

então coloquei um

```
<input type="hidden" name="question1" ng-model="question1">
```

com essa tentativa

```
php $alternativastentativa[0] = "question1" ?>
```

Esse `ng-model="question1"` vem do `js` onde ele recebe o valor de 1 a 5 de acordo com em que botão o usuário clicar.

FOCO NESSA PARTE:

Estou tentando com esse código comparar e não tenho a minima ideia de como se faz corretamente:
`$respostacerta1 = 4` (Coloquei valores padrões até funcionar)

```
<?php 
   if ($respostacerta1 == $alternativastentativa[0]){
       $contadoracertos = $contadoracertos++;
   }
?>
```